# Deny or Allow spesific user to connect my LocalIIS server

Tags: iis

I just need an idea about ı want to control who can use my web application.For example I am using my web application on local IIS . I want x computer can see my web application but y computer can not .I need an approach.

thanks for help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for IP or domain restrictions.
Check this http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/configuring-security/using-dynamic-ip-restrictions